# Extra "room" word in chat suspension sentence

Tags: bug, status-completed, spelling, chat-ban

I found a [sentence in traducir](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16636) during making translations:

> Link to room chat room where issue occurred (if available)

It seems that the first "room" should be eliminated.

You can see this message via [Contact page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact):

> [image: room chat room - home sweet home]

Comment: I wonder how long that sentence has been there. And surprised none of the suspended users that filled-out this form reported it earlier ... I guess they were not in the mood for it ...

Comment: @rene since there were no translations (at least for ruSO) I think that section was recently added to the site.

Comment: @rene Considering the form is only about two weeks old... about two weeks. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The superfluous word has been removed

---

> mod suspends user
> having chat room privileges
> remove extra word

Comment: huh, is "privileges" pronounced "priv-lij-es"? I've always said it "priv-ih-lej-es" but that wouldn't fit the 5-7-5

Comment: @hyper-neutrino I asked myself the same question. I pronounce it with 3 syllables, so I went with that.

Comment: Can't find the new sentence in https://ru.traducir.win/ yet