# Chat suspension sentence on the Contact page cannot be localized

Tags: bug, status-completed, localization, contact

Several days ago, I posted a bug report: [Extra "room" word in chat suspension sentence](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/366455/extra-room-word-in-chat-suspension-sentence)

That question was marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), but the issue looks like it wasn't completed as well as it could have been. In particular, the new sentence without the extra "room" seems to not be wrapped for localization purposes, i.e. I can't find that sentence in the Transifex/ Traducir database.

It still shows the English version on international Stack Overflow sites:

> Link to chat room where issue occurred (if available)

To reproduce, visit [this page](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/contact) and select the 9th item from the drop-down.

[My comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/366455/extra-room-word-in-chat-suspension-sentence#comment1221259_366528) under the answer on that question hasn't gotten a reply yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Now I see that sentence on [Traducir](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16643). Thanks for fixing.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, it looks like localization issues on the Contact page are all over the place. Here are some of the examples I found:

**[es.stackoverflow.com](https://es.stackoverflow.com/contact):**

[image]

**[pt.stackoverflow.com](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/contact)**

[image]

[image]

**[ja.stackoverflow.com](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/contact):**

[image]

Comment: These likely just have not been translated into those languages yet, given that they are translated on other sites. Users on the site do that when new strings become available, not us, and they default to English if they are not translated yet.